# Do Software Engineering degrees look considerably worse than Computer Science degrees on a resume?

Tags: job-search, united-states, recruitment

Universities are starting to add Software Engineering degree pathways, but traditionally people have pursued Computer Science degrees if they want to do software engineering.  From a recruiter or manager's perspective is there anything about a Software Engineering degree title that makes a candidate look worse when placed against an equally qualified candidate that has a Computer Science degree instead?  Does it really matter in the end?

Comment: Assuming it's a real engineering degree, I would think employers would hold it in higher regard than a Computer Science degree

Comment: @GregoryCurrie At my university it is.  Really the main difference between the SE and CS degrees at my university is that the CS degree has more physics and math involved while the SE degree foregoes some of that in exchange for more CS course electives.  I'm considering switching, but have been concerned that the "newness" of the degree title may deter recruiters.

Comment: I'm surprised because at my university, the core engineering maths subject was a lot harder than the comp sci maths.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie what's your criterion for something being a 'real engineering degree'? I believe there are some places in the world where 'Engineer' is a legally-protected designation, is that what you're referring to?

Comment: @AakashM A degree in engineering that has the core engineering subjects, specialising in something to do with computing.

Comment: @AakashM But your distinction is probably also accurate too.

Comment: @AakashM By the way. I have an engineering degree, and a computer science degree. The former was to ensure I could get a job. The latter because I found it interesting.

Comment: What country is this? I started a Software Engineering degree in 1998 in the UK. I actually didn't finish it and went back to Uni in 2005 to do a different degree with a similar title Computing (Software Engineering).  My friends who did finish the degree are all working in related fields 21 years later.

Comment: @Dustybin80 United States.  Outside of community colleges, degrees with the title "Software Engineer" are still quite new and are few and far between compared to "Computer Science" degrees.

Comment: @VisualStudio I think a country tag would help then as I assume you're focused on the US job market? Applying in the UK I don't think this title would hurt you in the slightest as it was fairly common certainly since 98 when I was looking for courses.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It doesn't. With very few exceptions, the job market actually needs software engineers, not computer scientists. Computer science is what you need for research if you want to stay in academia. It just overlapped a lot with what companies looking for software engineers needed, so they took what they could get.

It obviously depends on the actual courses you took and the actual jobs you want, but I don't see that it would make any difference.

Comment: A small anecdote: at my university, both the computer engineering program and the computer science program offered software engineering pathways.

Comment: Additional anecdote - I've never seen it matter on the employee side of things. All people seemed to care about was a STEM degree and programming experience.

Answer (score 11):

The main problem with computer science degrees is that they're often very theoretical - so while they give a strong foundation, they may not teach much in the way of actually useful skills.

You get CS graduates who have a good understanding of formal logic, but know nothing about source control. Who know assembly but not any higher level languages. Who understand how CPU schedulers work, but have never written multi-threaded code. Who can explain in detail how a TPM works, but have no idea how to write secure code. Who can design a circuit out of logic gates, but have no idea how HTTP works.

And there are roles where you absolutely need that low-level knowledge. If you're hiring people to write performance-critical algorithms, or code for embedded systems, or various other areas, you need someone who understands CPUs and registers and how thing *actually* work under the hood.

But the majority of developers don't do that kind of work. They work at a much higher level, with higher level languages and frameworks. They need to work in teams, and use source control, and CI/CD pipelines, and all the things that make them a *developer*, rather than just a *programmer*. And a good software engineering degree should teach more of those skills, so they can probably become useful to the organisation more quickly.

But in both cases, just saying that you have a degree doesn't really tell them much about what you know and can do. You should also be explaining some of the (more useful) things that you degree covered, and also the stuff that you've done outside of the degree. Someone who can point to a GitHub repo of code they've written, and the open source projects they've contributed to is a far better bet than someone who's got a computer science or software engineering degree, but hasn't done any development outside of it.

Comment: As a hiring manager, if someone can understand formal logic then I'm darn sure they can learn how to use source code control. If they understand CPU schedulers they can learn to write multi-threaded code. I'd rather have someone smart and teach them the skills they need.

Comment: @DJClayworth If your organisation has the time and resources to train them up then that's fine - and they may well end up being a better developer down the line. The person who knows assembly and CPU architecture may well be a better developer in six months: but the one who knows NodeJS and Git is going to be more useful today.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to point out that many organizations recruit for understanding and ability rather than "skills" (many of which will be out of date in five years) and so a CS degree is not worse than an SE degree, and in a couple of years when you've learned how to use Git and write C# it may well be landing you a better job.

Answer (score 7):

#### No, nor does it look better

My search of the universities that I and my kids have been asociated with shows this is a rare major.

Neither Harvard, Georgia Tech, University of Georgia, University of Florida, nor Louisiana State University offer Software Engineering as an undergraduate major.  They offer Computer Engineering, which is more of a type of coding EE who build computers.  Purdue has a "track" of SE in their Computer Science major.

That said, I do have knowledge of what a recent Computer Science degree includes, and it is a lot of coding, projects, source control, etc.  As such, I have trouble believing that companies are looking for true "Software Engineers" (because where would they find them?) or that Computer Science degrees aren't up to the job of preparing graduates for the workforce.  My company is filled with Computer Science majors, and they don't seem too theoretical to me.  It also has a lot of people who just learned this stuff outside of a university, which also seems to work out fine.

This has nothing to do with people calling themselves or their roles Software Engineers, which is just a different name for coders in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Employers care about what you can do, not what your degree says. In many places hiring managers will look at a degree simply as "this person has shown they can be on time, and study material to learn from it for four years without screwing up too bad" (not that there isn't clear value in that, in learning to manage your time, and having a strong background in the field you pursue). Especially in technology people realize the limited practical applications of what you learn in school, if for no other reason than what you learned about freshman year may be outdated*.

For some background, almost a decade ago I was in a similar situation in school, except I was looking at Information Systems (IS) and CS. I ended up doing IS with a CS minor because I wanted the expanded background in business, marketing, accounting, and more focus on practical, functional, scripting than theory that came with our IS degree. I kept the CS minor for the calculus requirements/generally to show employers I had a handle on theory as well. I've held several positions as a software engineer since, but the business acumen gained from the IS courses has been invaluable every step of the way.

Long way to say **pursue what makes sense to you, and don't be afraid to move away from what academia values to get practical value from courses you *want* to take**. Having been in hiring positions a few times in the past, and interviewing plenty of candidates, I think it would be silly to rule out a prospect because they have a Software Engineering degree rather than a Computer Science degree. SpaceX, NASA, Boeing, Lockheed, GD, etc *might* rule it out for a very specific position, but in general, you'll be considered equally and your presentation and knowledge in interviews will be far more important.

(*) this is where the CS degree does hold value, the pure theory doesn't change as rapidly as the technologies used to actually do things in the business world.

Answer (score -8):

Let me think when was the last time I needed anything related to computer science at my job... That would have been NEVER.

Now mathematics... I've used that a few times. Never anything hard, but enough so that someone without mathematics was completely, utterly stuck. Things like positioning three buttons on the screen, side by side, with equal distance between the buttons and the side.

Comment: Sounds like you'd have been better off with a Build Your Own Website in 24 Hours book. I still use things learned in my CS degree from finite state machine theory to Karnaugh Maps.

Comment: If you ever worked on air traffic control, flight control software, signal processing, and other mission critical systems, you would know the importance of high level mathematics.

Comment: Just because you do not implement the algorithms does not mean your education did not help you when evaluating others work, like when choosing with library or algorithm implementation to use.